# How to check if the user scrolled to 30% of an element, from the top or the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

As specified in the title, I'm listening to `scroll` event in order to fire a function when 30% of a `video` shows up in the window - regardless whether the user scrolls up or down.

What is have is this:

```
// On DOM ready, I set the top and bottom offset of the video,
// +/- 30% of the video height

var $video = $('#js-b2b-video');
var videoHeight = $video.outerHeight();
var videoHeight30 = parseInt(videoHeight/3, 10); // Approx. 30% of the video height
var videoObj = {}

videoObj.top = $video.offset().top + videoHeight30; // Approx. 30% from the top of the video
videoObj.bottom = videoObj.top + videoHeight - videoHeight30; // Approx. 30% from the bottom of the video
```

Then, the scroll event:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= videoObj.top) {
        alert('30% from the top of the video reached');
    }
});
```

However, this fires too late, when the video is fully visible. What I need is to fire my function immediately when 30% of the top or bottom of the video is visible.

How do I do this properly?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1k8xop6e/)**

Comment: Maybe try drawing a picture. `scrollTop` is the top of the viewport, it sounds like you want to check when the *bottom* of the viewport has passed 30% of the height of the video.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the window height into account.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= videoObj.top) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to consider the window height as well:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight >= videoObj.top) {
```

Note that you might want to test on *onload* and *resize* too...

[Try it](https://jsfiddle.net/1k8xop6e/1/)